# What a correct way to link facebook profile to existing account if i use jwt auth?

Tags: node.js, facebook, express, passport.js

read a lot of stuff about theme, but can't find beautiful way to link existing local strategy account with facebook strategy account.

The problem is i have JWT authorization, so if user click to "Connect FB account" button, he redirect to facebook, than back to server w/o JWT. Is there any way to send FB request with some user identity, that get back to me in callback url?

What correct way to link FB account to currently logged in user?

**UPD**
Found a way to send request / get callback with parameter:

```
const facebook = new FacebookStrategy.Strategy({
    ...facebookConfigAndScopes,
    passReqToCallback: true
  },
  (req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {console.log(req.params.id);}
);

userRouter.route('/auth/facebook/:id')
.get((req, res, next) => passport.authenticate('facebook', {
    scope: ['public_profile'],
    callbackURL: '/api/user/auth/facebook/callback/'+req.params.id
  })(req, res, next)
);

userRouter.route('/auth/facebook/callback/:id')
.get(
  (req, res, next) =>  passport.authenticate('facebook', { callbackURL: '/api/user/auth/facebook/callback/'+req.params.id })(req, res, next),
);
```

So i can send user hash to identify existing user.

Answer (score 0):

Use `state` parameter to pass the token to Facebook. Facebook will add the data in `state` parameter while calling the callback url.

More info here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#logindialog

Comment: Thats not a problem to get user profile from facebook. Problem is to link existing user account with facebook user after redirect to callback. I don't have any user in server session.

Comment: Facebook is giving you the user's email. You don't need a user in session to know which user was that. Just check it's email id and match with your database. That's the user!

Comment: User can have different emails;

For example user sign up with a@gmail.com, then from his account page he push button "Connect to FB", and api get response from FB with b@gmail.com. And API create new user, whats bit surprising.

Comment: Nice point. I have updated the answer to reflect this. If you have control on frontend, you can add the `state` parameter to facebook request.